# convert Date column to string / label if NOT IsDBNull

Tags: vb.net, date-conversion

I am trying (much too long) to convert a DateTime column to a label.Text.

Various errors:

What am I missing?

```
drExpDatesRow = dtAllCompanies.Select("CompanyID = " + CompanyID.ToString())

    Dim ls_ExpiresDateString As String
    If (Not IsDBNull(drExpDatesRow("Expdate"))) Then
        Date.TryParse(drExpDatesRow("Expdate").ToString(), ls_ExpiresDateString)
        'ls_ExpiresDateString = ldt_ExpiresDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        lbl_ExpireDate.Text = ls_ExpiresDateString.ToString()
    Else
        lbl_ExpireDate.Text = ""
    End If
```

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled   Message=Conversion from
>   string "Expdate" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
>   Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String
>   Value)
>          at zzz.winCompanyInfo.CompanyInfo_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\zzz.vb:line 638
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)   InnerException:
>   System.FormatException
>          Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
>          Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String
>   Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
>               at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String
>   Value)
>          InnerException:

UPDATE** Added DataRow logic

Comment: Hmm are you sure the code that you posted is where the error occurs? Your error states that you are trying to convert "Expdate" to an integer

Comment: If this is a snippet of your average coding then please turn strict on ASAP. `TryParse` is defined `TryParse(ByVal Object, ByRef Date)` so ls_ExpiresDateString should be a `Date` not a `String`. Btw, a variable declared as a `String` will never be anything other than a `String`. So there is no need to call `ToString` for a `String`.

Comment: I will look into how to turn strict on for now, ty for that tip.

Comment: Your `drExpDatesRow = dtAllCompanies.Select("CompanyID = " + CompanyID.ToString())` returns array of rows. So you need to do `IsDBNull(drExpDatesRow(0)("Expdate"))`. But also check the length of array first - may be there nothing found

Answer (score 2):

When using `TryParse` use the same data type.

```
Dim drExpDatesRow = (From dr As DataRow In dtAllCompanies.Rows 
                     Where dr("CompanyId").ToString =
                     CompanyID.ToString).FirstOrDefault

Dim ls_ExpiresDate As Date      ' Date not String
If (Not drExpDatesRow Is Nothing) Then
  If Date.TryParse(drExpDatesRow("Expdate").ToString(), ls_ExpiresDate)
    lbl_ExpireDate.Text = ls_ExpiresDate.ToString()
  End If
Else
    lbl_ExpireDate.Text = ""
End If
```

Comment: Still stuck with same exception. I am doing a quickwatch on the datarow and I can see the value is NULL - but I coded for that??

Comment: Try the above change.

Comment: ty for trying. Same error. I will keep working on it. System.InvalidCastException

Comment: If you hover over the `drExpDatesRow` what does it say that object is? A collection of datarows - most likely!

Comment: @OneFineDay iven if it was one row `Not drExpDatesRow("Expdate") Is Nothing` probably incorrect. I think, you need to check for DBNull

Comment: Use a lambda expression to get it. If it does not find a row then the object will be `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

You had multiple issues in your code. This one should take care of things for good

```
drExpDatesRow = dtAllCompanies.Select("CompanyID = " + CompanyID.ToString()) ' returns array

lbl_ExpireDate.Text = ""
If drExpDatesRow.Length > 0 Then

    If (Not IsDBNull(drExpDatesRow(0)("Expdate"))) Then

        Dim myDate As DateTime
        Dim res As Boolean = Date.TryParse(drExpDatesRow("Expdate"), myDate)

        If res Then lbl_ExpireDate.Text = MyDate.ToString("<format>")
    End If
End If
```